# Escaping the double quote that is in the attribute of an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a HTML page having a attribute. When i insert the attribute named "control_label". When i assign a value "Enters Your Name" in this attribute everything is okay.

But when i try to add a value say "  **Enters Your Name"**   "  having a single double quote the value of the attribute does not become  **Enters Your Name"** . Even i tried a Escape character like **Enters Your Name\"** the value becomes **Enters Your Name\** and not **Enters Your Name"**.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3UUH/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Beetle952580 Thanks for posting duplicate comment after 3.5 years for an accepted answer. I don't doubt you are posting comment unnecessary :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HTML doesn't use `\` to escape characters, it uses entities.

```
&quot;
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape `"` as `&quot;`

That will make browser not parse it.

```
value="Enter Your Name&quot;"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&quot;` instead of a backslash

Comment: @RokKralj I would say that "instead" is OK, but it is "can" that is not the right word :)