# double quotes use in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm adding an hidden input as something in a select is choosen, using the onchange event with some jsp vars. I add some text to the div I'm working on but there are too many quotes and double quotes so I don't understand how to do it. Does anyone have any idea?

`<select name="opt_name%>" onchange="$('#dati_opzioni').append('<input type="hidden" name="optdesc_'+<%=opt.getCdOpzione()%>+'" value="'+<%=optLabel%>+'_'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].text+'"/>');">`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007672/escaping-the-double-quote-that-is-in-the-attribute-of-an-html-tag

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer and more readable to use event listeners instead of inline handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using html entities for double quotes (as & quot; without blanks) inside the onchange="..."

```
<select name="opt_name%>" onchange="$('#dati_opzioni').append('<input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;optdesc_'+<%=opt.getCdOpzione()%>+'&quot; value=&quot;'+<%=optLabel%>+'_'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].text+'&quot;/>');">
```

Comment: Won't work, attributes don't use `\\` escape sequences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007672/escaping-the-double-quote-that-is-in-the-attribute-of-an-html-tag

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select name="<%=opt_name%>" onchange="$('#dati_opzioni').append('<input type=""hidden"" name=""optdesc_'+<%=opt.getCdOpzione()%>+'"" value=""'+<%=optLabel%>+'_'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].text+'""/>');">
```