# Get JSON value from input element

Tags: jquery, json

I have an input element with a value that looks like this:

```
value="{"logEntries":[],"value":"CHCN1","text":"CHCN AAH COMPLETE CARE (CHCN1)","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}"
```

When I retrieve the value thru jQuery all I get is the first { since its wrapped in quotes... How do I get the entire JSON object??

Comment: Your input element is totally invalid, it can only have one `value` attribute

Comment: Use single quotes around the value

Comment: [Escaping the double quote that is in the attribute of an HTML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007672/escaping-the-double-quote-that-is-in-the-attribute-of-an-html-tag)

Comment: or assign the value in script and then set the value to JSON.stringify(object)

Comment: The value is created by a Telerik control. I can't change it to single quotes or otherwise change the value.

Comment: @ScottLoveland If the control is generating the markup incorrectly, it's not going to be reasonably possible to recover it after the fact. This seems like a bug in the control that Telerik would want to know about.

Comment: Indeed, turns out they somehow use it, I have no Idea how but regardless I found that they have a client side method I was able to use to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 0):

In a node.js console, for instance, you can run `JSON.parse()` on a single-quoted string to turn it into a callable JSON object:

```
> value = JSON.parse('{"logEntries":[], "value":"CHCN1","text":"CHCN AAH COMPLETE CARE (CHCN1)","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}');
{ logEntries: [],
  value: 'CHCN1',
  text: 'CHCN AAH COMPLETE CARE (CHCN1)',
  enabled: true,
  checkedIndices: [],
  checkedItemsTextOverflows: false }
> value.value
'CHCN1'
>
```

You would not need jQuery to parse a String into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the content from a server.

If you instead do

```
$(function() {
  var jsObj = {"logEntries":[],"value":"CHCN1","text":"CHCN AAH COMPLETE CARE (CHCN1)","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}
  $("#inputId").val(JSON.stringify(jsObj));
});
```

If not possible you need to change the input to

```
<input value='{....}' />
```

Answer (score -2):

The input field's value (especially the double quoutes) is not properly escaped.  Escape the double quotes with a leading backslash.

Comment: You cannot have escaped double quotes in an input field that has value=""